# ToolStripButton при наведении мыши исчезает фоновое изображение(BackgroundImage), что делать?

Tags: c#, winforms

При наведении мыши на ToolStripButton, исчезает фоновое изображение (BackgroundImage), что делать ? Вот сделал скриншоты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А код нам полагается угадать?

Comment: А смысл от кода ? Это по умолчанию так, в любом проекте. У меня Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй свойство ToolStripButton.Image вместо .BackgroundImage

Comment: Так и приходится делать, но как быть, если нужно именно BackgroundImage ?

Comment: Почему именно его?